# Remove empty entries from list of list of strings

Tags: c#, list, linq

I'm looking for a more efficient way of removing empty string values from a list of a list of strings.

The code below works but for a very large data set this seems inefficient. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

**FYI - The beginning is just to build a Data Set to have a list of a list that contains empty strings**

```
public static void Main()
{       
    //Building the data set
    List<List<string>> list = new List<List<string>>();
    list.Add(new List<string> {"One", "Two", "", "Eight"});
    list.Add(new List<string> {"Three", "Five", "Six"});
    list.Add(new List<string> {"Sixteen", "", ""});
    list.Add(new List<string> {"Twenty-Eight", "Forty", "Nine"});

    //Create an empty List of a List
    List<List<string>> newList = new List<List<string>>();

    //Loop through the original list and purge each list of empty strings
    for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) {
        newList.Add(list[i].Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToList());
    }

    foreach (var s in newList) {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", s));    
    }

    /*
    CORRECT OUTPUT:
        "One", "Two", "Eight"
        "Three", "Five", "Six"
        "Sixteen"
        "Twenty-Eight", "Forty", "Nine"         
    */      
}
```

Comment: Since they are lists, you could use `List.RemoveAll()` instead, that way you're not creating new lists to replace the ones you currently have.

Comment: Lists are mutable; do you want to mutate the existing lists, or create new ones?  Both are reasonable choices.

Comment: You say that you are worried about "efficiency" but efficiency is value produced divided by resources consumed; what value are you producing, and what resource are you consuming?

Comment: Good questions. I want to simply remove the empty strings in every child list.

Comment: If you want to remove all of a thing, the aptly-named `RemoveAll` method should be your go-to choice.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why not use the [**List<T>.RemoveAll()**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall) method? Definition:

> Removes all the elements that match the conditions defined by the specified predicate.

```
foreach (var l in list)
{
    l.RemoveAll(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));
}
```

That is all you need. Other answer have `Select().Where()` and twice `ToList()`, which is way too much overhead for a simple action like this.

Comment: Interesting.. You believe this is faster than the one-liner LINQ statements above?

Comment: @bagofmilk The speed difference is not going to be that much, but this consumes much less memory in that it doesn't need to create a new list of lists.

Comment: @bagofmilk: Which one is faster really doesn't matter unless this particular task represents a performance bottleneck in your application.  What's more important is that Abbas's code is easier to read.  Personally, I prefer the use of method groups (`l.RemoveAll(string.IsNullOrEmpty);`) instead of lambdas (applies to most of the answers to your question).  I'll note that if you insist on a one-liner, you still don't need LINQ: Just use (`list.ForEach(x=>x.RemoveAll(String.IsNullOrEmpty))`).  Though personally, I'm not a fan of `List<T>.ForEach`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want a `List<List<string>>` returned then just `Select` and filter with the inner list with `Where`

```
public List<List<string>> FilterStrings()
{
    List<List<string>> list = new List<List<string>>();
    list.Add(new List<string> { "One", "Two", "", "Eight" });
    list.Add(new List<string> { "Three", "Five", "Six" });
    list.Add(new List<string> { "Sixteen", "", "" });
    list.Add(new List<string> { "Twenty-Eight", "Forty", "Nine" });

    return list.Select(lst => lst.Where(str => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)).ToList()).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
newList = list.Select(t=>t.Where(q=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(q)).ToList()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The main idea: iterate through lists and remove empty strings from each.

`list.Select(outerListItem => 
    outerListItem.Where(innerListItem =>
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(innerListItem).ToList())`